# How to break a for loop in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have the following function:

```
(defn next-transformation
  [arr]
  (let [
        arr-len (count arr)
        i-range (range 0 arr-len)
        j-range (range 0 arr-len)
        indexes (for [i i-range
                      j j-range]
              (let [
                   xi (nth arr i)
                   xj (nth arr j)
                   ]
                (if (> xi xj)
                  [i j] 
                  nil
                  )
               )
            ) 
        non-nil-indexes (filter
                         (fn [elem]
                           (not (= elem nil))
                           )
                         indexes 
                        ) 
        ]
    (if (not (empty? non-nil-indexes))
       (first non-nil-indexes)
       nil
      )
    )
)
```

It returns the first element of an array of tuples `[i j]` which describe elments of the array `arr` for which `arr[i] > arr[j]` is true.

The `for` loop in the fragment below runs through every pair of i and j:

```
indexes (for [i i-range
              j j-range]
      (let [
           xi (nth arr i)
           xj (nth arr j)
           ]
        (if (> xi xj)
          [i j] ;; I want the loop to stop here
          nil
          )
       )
    )
```

How can I modify this for loop so that it stops once it finds the first relevant tuple (i. e. the loop should stop at the place marked with `;; I want the loop to stop here` comment)?

Here is the equivalent code in Java:

```
private Integer[] next-transformation(final Integer[] arr) {
  for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j < arr.length; j++) {
       if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
         return new Integer[] {i, j};
       }
     }
  }

}
```

**Update 1:**

As recommended by @CharlesDuffy, I replaced `for` with `loop`/`recur`:

```
(defn next-transformation
  [arr]
  (loop [i 0
         j 0]
    (let [
          arr-len (count arr)
          ]
      (if (and (< i arr-len)
               (< j arr-len))
        (let [
                xi (nth arr i)
                xj (nth arr j)
                j-plus-1 (+ j 1)
                i-plus-1 (+ i 1)
                new-i (if (< j-plus-1 arr-len)
                       i
                       (+ i 1))
                new-j (if (< j-plus-1 arr-len)
                       (+ j 1)
                       0)
              ]
          (if (> xi xj)
              ;; We found it
              [i j] 
              ;; We haven't found it, recur 
              (recur new-i new-j)
            )
          )
          nil ; We are at the end of the  loop
        ) ; if 
      )
    ) ; loop 
  ) ; defn
```

Comment: `for` in Clojure shouldn't be thought of as a loop. It's a _sequence definition_; that it can be used for flow control is a side effect, not the main purpose.

Comment: ...that said, see `:while` inside `for`.

Comment: But if you want to stop after the first item is returned, why not just `take 1` from the generated sequence? (There actually _is_ a valid answer to that "why not?", about how Clojure sequences are chunked and not handled at an item-by-item level of laziness, but that's a place where a performance optimization is making real-world behavior a bit different from the theoretical ideal; it's worth knowing and understanding what the theoretical ideals are, though, if you want to be able to write idiomatic code).

Comment: ...anyhow, for your actual use case, I would generally go with `loop`/`recur` and not `for` at all. Picking-the-correct-tool-for-the-job, and all.

Comment: (also, if you use `:when` in your `for`, you don't need to make the caller responsible for skipping the `nil`s)

Comment: `for` is not like the looping construct you are used from imperative languages, but it's an "list comprehension". Clojure is not another "LISP transpiler" for an underlying language but is an functional programming language with immutable data structures.  So this is quite some shift in mind-set so don't dig to deep in your "imperative" brain areas for solving koans like this.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your comments. I have a question: Is `non-nil-indexes` a lazy sequence?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Re *..anyhow, for your actual use case, I would generally go with loop/recur*: Is my solution in *Update 1* correct (conforms to the letter and spirit of Clojure)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `for` list comprehension, use `:when` to filter for the tuples of interest, and use `first` to return just the first one:

```clj
(defn next-transformation [arr]
  (first (for [i (range (count arr))
               j (range (count arr))
               :when (> (nth arr i) (nth arr j))]
           [i j])))
```